# Exception of type 'Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiDashboardAssemblyIsNotFoundException' was thrown

Tags: dashboard, stimulsoft

I use Stimulsoft 2020.2.1
I've designed a dashboard.
When executing below code:
 **report.Load(Server.MapPath(ReportPath))**

Returns the following exeption:
**Exception of type 'Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiDashboardAssemblyIsNotFoundException' was thrown**

Exception of type 'Stimulsoft.Base.Serializing.StiDashboardAssemblyIsNotFoundException' was thrown

Displays regular reports without problems. Only gives this expansion for the dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved By Install Stimulsoft.Dashboards.Web using nuget